# JSON object mapper for Python

Tags: python, json

Basically I am automating the API in python, API returns JSON as response looks like below

In java I can validate the schema using POJO Model using Gson lib like as fallow -

```
GetCustomerModel - is my custom POJO class have so 3 inner classes.
GetCustomerModel body = new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(),GetCustomerModel.class);
```

Is there any lib support in Python to do same, I mean conver json as custom python mapping object ?

```
[{
    "businessUnit": {
        "code": "27888",
        "type": "LSCCC"
    },
    "timeWindows": [
        {
            "freeCapacity": true,
            "capacityTemplateIdentifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "cutOff": "2020-11-30T17:00:00Z",
            "end": "2020-11-30T17:00:00Z",
            "maxCapacity": 0,
            "start": "2020-11-30T08:00:00Z",
            "timeWindowIdentifier": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
            "tspId": "9900001"
        }
    ],
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
}]
```

Python Model -

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from uuid import UUID
from typing import List


@dataclass
class BusinessUnit:
    code: int
    type: str


@dataclass
class TimeWindow:
    free_capacity: bool
    capacity_template_identifier: str
    cut_off: datetime
    end: datetime
    max_capacity: int
    start: datetime
    time_window_identifier: UUID
    tsp_id: int


@dataclass
class WelcomeElement:
    business_unit: BusinessUnit
    time_windows: List[TimeWindow]
    time_zone: str
```

My code -

```
result = from_dict(data_class=WelcomeElement, data=response.content)
```

Gives an error saying - "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Python's standard library includes [the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) which can be used to input/output JSON to python dicts; and there's a [third-party `jsonschema` module](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) I found with a quick google search that seems to do the validation you're looking for. You'd do the validation and the processing in separate steps, presumably.

Comment: pip install dacite

Comment: I have tried with both json and Jsonschema it only converts json to python Object using namespaces, but here I need a mapping class to validate the API response  with my own python object.

Comment: @balderman - I have installed dacite but I got the fallowing error after my line execute-"tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"
result = from_dict(data_class=WelcomeElement, data=toi_api_detail_object[0])

Comment: You need to share the code. The error is not clear

Comment: Post the code is a question - not in comment. It is hard to follow.

Comment: @balderman I have pasted the code in the quesion section

Comment: @sureshullagaddi you need to format it.

Comment: @balderman I have formatted the code but it looks odd after save

Comment: `response.content` is a list with 1 dict  - right? You are passing the list and not the dict

Comment: @balderman Thank  you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below works:

Few points to improve:

- use type hooks in order convert data types
- deal with [camelCase and snake_case](https://medium.com/better-programming/string-case-styles-camel-pascal-snake-and-kebab-case-981407998841)

  ```
    from dataclasses import dataclass
    from datetime import datetime
    from uuid import UUID
    from typing import List
    from dacite import from_dict


    @dataclass
    class BusinessUnit:
        code: int
        type: str


    @dataclass
    class TimeWindow:
        free_capacity: bool
        capacity_template_identifier: str
        cut_off: str
        end: str
        max_capacity: int
        start: str
        time_window_identifier: str
        tsp_id: int


    @dataclass
    class WelcomeElement:
        business_unit: BusinessUnit
        time_windows: List[TimeWindow]
        time_zone: str

    data = [{
        "business_unit": {
            "code": 27888,
            "type": "LSCCC"
        },
        "time_windows": [
            {
                "free_capacity": True,
                "capacity_template_identifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "cut_off": "2020-11-30T17:00:00Z",
                "end": "2020-11-30T17:00:00Z",
                "max_capacity": 0,
                "start": "2020-11-30T08:00:00Z",
                "time_window_identifier": "yyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                "tsp_id": 9900001
            }
        ],
        "time_zone": "Europe/London"
    }]

    print('start')
    result = from_dict(data_class=WelcomeElement, data=data[0])
    print(result)
  ```

  output

  ```
    start
    WelcomeElement(business_unit=BusinessUnit(code=27888, type='LSCCC'), time_windows=[TimeWindow(free_capacity=True, capacity_template_identifier='xxxxxxxxxxxx', cut_off='2020-11-30T17:00:00Z', end='2020-11-30T17:00:00Z', max_capacity=0, start='2020-11-30T08:00:00Z', time_window_identifier='yyyyyyyyyyyyyy', tsp_id=9900001)], time_zone='Europe/London')
  ```